# Springboot not returning index.jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I am running my Sprinboot Application, it is just returning index as string. It is not giving me index.jsp page. Also I have tried to add some jstl compiler in it still it is not working

The code of Main file:

```
package com.hello.first;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FirstApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The Controller file:

```
package com.hello.first;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class firstpage {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**Application.properties:**

server.port=8000

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/

spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp

**POM.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>first</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>first</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello this is my page!!
</body>
</html>
```

Output I am getting:

```
index
```

Comment: You need to use `@Controller` instead of  `@RestController`.

Comment: After changing it, it is giving error /WEB_INF/index.jsp not found. The place where I have kept my index.js is - src/main/webapp/WEB_INF/index.js

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by replacing the `return "index"` with `return "index.html"` and replacing the files from templates folder to static folder as I was simply trying to return simple HTML file.

Also the above code is working fine if I add thymeleaf dependancy

Answer (score 0):

use

```
return "index.jsp"  instead 
 return "index"
```